# Same app diaplayed twice in Data sense

Tags: 8.1, datasense

In my Data sense app, a single application (Hike messenger) has been displayed two times as if they are two apps. Here is the image :

[image: Screenshot]
[image: Screenshot-2]

I had then reset my data plan.Now Hike shows as a single app. Any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: Had you removed/reinstalled the app at all?

Comment: @RowlandShaw I had updated the app. But it has not happened like this during the previous updates.